# Leaflet AddCircleMarkers set to deselected until user selects - R SHINY

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have used code based on this example from :https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/4-tricks-for-working-with-r-leaflet-and-shiny/

I would like my map to start out with none of the circle markers added and then to have them added or removed as the user interacts with the available options.

This is how it currently looks when a user loads the map:
[image]

And this is how I would like it to look when a user loads the map:
[image]

I've tried removing groups and layers and nothing seems to work. I am very likely missing something quite obvious. Thanks :)

## Load libraries

```
 library(shiny)
 library(leaflet)

 # Make data with several positions
 data_red=data.frame(LONG=42+rnorm(10), LAT=23+rnorm(10), 
 PLACE=paste("Red_place_",seq(1,10)))
 data_blue=data.frame(LONG=42+rnorm(10), LAT=23+rnorm(10), 
 PLACE=paste("Blue_place_",seq(1,10)))

# Initialize the leaflet map:
leaflet() %>% 
setView(lng=42, lat=23, zoom=8 ) %>%

  # Add two tiles
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group="background 1") %>%
  addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE), group="background 
  2") %>%

   # Add 2 marker groups
   addCircleMarkers(data=data_red, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=8 , 
   color="black",  fillColor="red", stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8, 
   group="Red") %>%
   addCircleMarkers(data=data_blue, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=8 , color="black",  fillColor="blue", stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8, group="Blue") %>%

 # Add the control widget
 addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("Red","Blue") , baseGroups = c("background 1","background 2"), options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
```

**ACTUAL CODE based on example above**

```
           ui <- shiny::fluidPage("Logan Service Response Map", 
                   div(class="outer",
                                 tags$head(
                                   # Include our custom CSS
                                   includeCSS("styles.css")),
                    leafletOutput("map", width="100%", height="100%"),

                selectInput("stats", "",
                                    label="Select an ABS statistic to display on the map.",
                                    choices = list("Population per SA2"="sum_pop",
                                             "Average weekly income" = "inc_pw",
                                             "Average income" = "Mean",
                                             "Median income"="Median",
                                             "Age Pension recipients"= "Age.Pension",
                                             "Low Income Card holders"= "Low.Income.Card",
                                             "Newstart Allowance recipients"= "Newstart.Allowance",
                                             "Commonwealth Rent Assistance recipients"="Commonwealth.Rent.Assistance..income.units.",
                                             "Carer Allowance recipients"="Carer.Allowance",
                                             "Disability Support Pension recipients"="Disability.Support.Pension",
                                             "Family Tax Benefit A recipients"="Family.Tax.Benefit.A",
                                             'Family Tax Benefit B recipients'="Family.Tax.Benefit.B",
                                             "Gini co-efficient"="Gini.coefficient"))

         tags$div(id="cite",
                                      br(),
                                      'Data from ABS and Service location data compiled by Logan Together 2018/2019.'
                             ))

      server <- function(input, output, session){

   pal<-c("#85499A","#660066","#EE3A32","orange","#FCD30B","#006666",
     "#330066","turquoise","red","#235766","#1D9DD9","#A1DDFA",
     "pink","#7AC04D")
    colourCount = length(unique(logan_sa2$SA2_NAME16))
     getPalette = colorRampPalette(pal)

    output$map<-renderLeaflet({

leaflet(logan_sa2) %>%
 addTiles()%>%
 setView(153, -27, zoom = 22)%>%

# Centre the map in the middle of our co-ordinates
 fitBounds(152.8, -27.7, 153.3, -27.6)
 })

   labels <- sprintf(
 "<strong>%s</strong><br/>
  SA2 Population: %s <br/><br/>
  Average weekly income: %s <br/><br/>
  Average total income: %s<br/><br/>
  Median total income: %s<br/><br/>
  Gini coefficient: %s<br/>", 
 logan_sa2$SA2_NAME16, logan_sa2$sum_pop,logan_sa2$inc_pw, logan_sa2$Mean, logan_sa2$Median,
 logan_sa2$Gini.coefficient) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)

   #creating a proxy map that displays the various stats from the stats drp down 
   leafletProxy("map", data = logan_sa2) %>%
    clearShapes() %>%
      addMeasure(primaryLengthUnit = "kilometers",
            primaryAreaUnit = "sqmeters",
            activeColor = "#3D535D",
            completedColor = "#7D4479")%>%
   addEasyButton(easyButton(
   icon="fa-crosshairs", title="Locate Me",
   onClick=JS("function(btn, map){ map.locate({setView: true}); }")))%>%
   addPolygons(
   layerId = logan_sa2$SA2_NAME16,
   group = "sa2_log",
   fillColor = ~pal(logan_sa2[[input$stats]]),
   fillOpacity = 0.6,
   weight = 0.6,
   opacity = 1,
   color = "#FFFFFF",
   dashArray = "2",
   label = labels,
   highlight = highlightOptions(
     weight = 4,
     color = "#FFFFFF",
     dashArray = "3",
     fillOpacity = 2,
     bringToFront = FALSE),
    labelOptions = labelOptions(
     style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 5px"),
     textsize = "13px",
     direction = "auto"))  %>%
   #addMarkers(data=marker_data())%>%
     #add markers for service types
     addCircleMarkers(data=Alcohol_Drugs, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black", 
                      fillColor="red", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Alcohol & Other Drugs", popup = labels_services) %>%
     addCircleMarkers(data=Child_Family, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black", 
                     fillColor="#da74e4", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Child & Family", popup = labels_services) %>%
     addCircleMarkers(data=Domestic_Family_Violence, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black", 
                      fillColor="#ea2525", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Domestic & Family Violence", popup = labels_services) %>%
     addCircleMarkers(data=Employment, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black",  
                     fillColor="#e28a3f", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Employment", popup = labels_services) %>% 
     addCircleMarkers(data=Finance, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black",  
                    fillColor="#1d8f8f", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Finance", popup = labels_services) %>% 
     addCircleMarkers(data=Health_Social_Connection_Wellbeing, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black",  
                      fillColor="#421076", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Health, Social Connection & Wellbeing", popup = labels_services) %>%
     addCircleMarkers(data=Housing_Homelessness, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #="black",  
                      fillColor="#a792e4", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Housing & Homelessness", popup = labels_services) %>%
     addCircleMarkers(data=Information_Advice_Referral, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black", 
                      fillColor="#e2c920", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Information Advice & Referral", popup = labels_services) %>%
     addCircleMarkers(data=Legal, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black",  
                     fillColor="#e27d3f", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Legal", popup = labels_services) %>%
     addCircleMarkers(data=Mental_Health, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black",  
                     fillColor="#e2c920", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Mental & Health", popup = labels_services) %>%
     addCircleMarkers(data=Migrant_Refugee, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black",  
                     fillColor="#7b0c22", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Migrant & Refugee", popup = labels_services) %>%
     addCircleMarkers(data=Sexual_Assault_Abuse, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black",  
                     fillColor="#33a4bf", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Sexual Assault & Abuse", popup = labels_services) %>%
     addCircleMarkers(data=Youth, lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT, radius=7 , #color="black",  
                     fillColor="#4a48b6", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 1, group="Youth", popup = labels_services) %>%

 #add map background theme options
    addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite", group="Background Map 1")%>%
    addTiles(options=providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE), group="Background Map 2")%>%
    addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("Background Map 1","Background Map 2"), options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))%>%    

 #add markers for service support level 
     #addAwesomeMarkers(data=Secondary,lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT,group="Secondary", icon=icons)%>%
     #addAwesomeMarkers(data=Early_Intervention_Prevention,lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT,group="Early Intervention & Prevention",icon=icons)%>%
     #addAwesomeMarkers(data=Tertiary,lng=~LONG , lat=~LAT,group="Tertiary",icon=icons)%>%
     #add layer controls
     addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("Alcohol & Other Drugs","Child & Family","Domestic & Family Violence","Employment","Finance",
                                       "Health, Social Connection & Wellbeing","Housing & Homelessness", "Information Advice & Referral",
                                      "Legal","Mental & Health","Migrant & Refugee","Sexual Assault & Abuse","Youth"),baseGroups = c("Background Map 1","Background Map 2"),
     options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))

       #this information is also displayed in the pop-ups for each clickable electorate
    varname<-switch(input$stats,
               "sum_pop"="Total population per SA2",                                                                                                                                                                                             "Electorate Population"="CED_pop_total",
               "inc_pw"="Average weekly income per SA2",
               "Mean"="Average (mean) total income per SA2",
               "Median"="Median total income per SA2",
               "Gini.coefficient"="Gini coefficient",
               "Age.Pension"="Number of Age Pension recipients",
               "Low.Income.Card"="Number of Low Income Card holders",
               "Newstart.Allowance"="Number of Newstart Allowance recipients",
               "Commonwealth.Rent.Assistance..income.units."="Number of Commonwealth Rent Assistance recipients",
               "Carer.Allowance"="Number of Carer Allowance recipients",
               "Disability.Support.Pension"="Numbers of Disability Support Pension recipients",
               "Family.Tax.Benefit.A"="Number of Family Tax Benefit A recipients",
               "Family.Tax.Benefit.B"='Number of Family Tax Benefit B recipients')

     leafletProxy("map", data = logan_sa2) %>% clearControls() %>%
           addLegend(pal = pal, opacity = 0.9, title = varname,
           values = ~logan_sa2[[input$stats]],labels = c(min(input$stats), max(input$stats)),
           position = "bottomright")
  }) 
 }


  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The code you've give doesn't seem to reflect the screenshot you've shared.

Comment: You are right they dont. I shared the example I based my code off of for simplicity sake I can add my exact code if that helps.

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into your question. Instead, post it as an answer so others may vote on it. I have reverted your edit.

Comment: Sorry So I post it as my own answer even though the suggestion cam from Alexander Leow's  suggestion? Sorry new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer based on the suggestion from Alexander Leow. I added all the groups to the  hideGroup argument.

```
  output$map<-renderLeaflet({

leaflet(logan_sa2) %>%
  addTiles()%>%
  hideGroup(c("Alcohol & Other Drugs","Child & Family","Domestic & Family Violence","Employment","Finance",
               "Health, Social Connection & Wellbeing","Housing & Homelessness", "Information Advice & Referral",
               "Legal","Mental & Health","Migrant & Refugee","Sexual Assault & Abuse","Youth"))%>%
  setView(153, -27, zoom = 22)%>%

  # Centre the map in the middle of our co-ordinates
  fitBounds(152.8, -27.7, 153.3, -27.6)
   })
```

This produces the desired result to have none of the checkboxes for the Circle markers selected when the map initially loads.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The solution is rather simple. Per default the groups are enabled in the control. You can switch them off by following command:

```
map %>% hideGroup("groupName")
```

For more information see here: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html

Comment: Would I need to do this for each group of markers (there are quite a few) I added my actual code above if that helps. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I got it and added all the Groups to the hideGroup argument - I've added an example of the code above. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your output code to something like `observeEvent` function, so that when an input is made then only the output shown and otherwise not.

Check the Trick2 and Trick4 from the same link you provided. Hope you will get an idea.

PS to Moderators: Sorry, My comment section is not activated yet thats why I had to make it in the answer section. You can move it to comments. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome I will have a look at this tomorrow morning and can mark it correct then. I had a feeling the solution would be simple!

Comment: thank you for the suggestion would I need to create an observe event for each group or markers? I've added my actual code above if that helps